# How do I display a React UI in SWT

Tags: java, reactjs

I am trying to load a Terra Component UI in SWT SHell. But i can only load the web pages using browser function in SWT and when i try to load the UI i get a blank screan. 
This is what i tried :

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class BrowserLoadingWebsite {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);


    Browser browser = new Browser(shell, SWT.NONE);
    browser.setBounds(5,5,600,600);
    //org.eclipse.swt.program.Program.launch("http://localhost:3000");
    browser.setUrl("http://localhost:3000/");    
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
      if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
  }
}
```